# Laravel Homestead: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined error

Tags: laravel-5, npm, vuejs2

This problem is driving me mad, I have been researching and have read about the standalone and runtime version of Vue. As far as I can tell Laravel 5.4/homestead ships with the standalone version as default.

The Vue development tools in chrome show the example component so I think that part is working correctly, just cannot render the template.

I am relatively new to Vue and npm been stuck in the past with jQuery, firstly where in laravel can I check/set I want the stand alone version of Vue? If it is not that problem does any one have any ideas?

Thanks for help

Comment: A bit more info... is it a fresh build? Did you just installed laravel and ran npm or did you change some stuff? Some people found the problem in their gulpfile where they called elixir more than once.

Comment: So you've run `npm install` and `npm run build` (if you're using 5.4) or `gulp`  (for earlier versions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by peaceman was the solution, I had multiple calls to elixir, I condensed down to one and it worked straight away. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

VueJS supports two ways of building apps like you said.

1. Load all necessary scripts within your page via script tags (not combined .vue files).
2. Compile and bundle all your files with Gulp, Browserify, Webpack or other tools.

Can you explain what you did so far. I guess you don't compile everything down.

Comment: I am using the laravel default component, laravel comes out of the box with gulp setup for Vue components.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/frontend#writing-vue-components

So I run gulp, load the page where I have the tags, the chrome Vue tool shows the "example" components however I get the error message mentioned in the title.